# Track down source of "eroneous" Xcode breakpoint trigger

Tags: xcode, debugging, ide, xcode6, breakpoints

I am getting several (annoying) triggered breakpoints for my project that don't seem to correlate with any real actionable exceptions. I have removed all breakpoints from my project, the only one being the "exception breakpoint." The issue is, is that when I run my project, it is being triggered in the main function and does not provide much detail about where the exception occurred...I can usually just skip over it (usually a couple times) without any issue. This has only recently started happening, but I am having trouble tracking down the source of what's actually triggering the breakpoint. I'm running Xcode 6.1.1, but the issue hasn't always occurred with the particular version I am using. I have included some screenshots of my configuration/the triggered break point:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was listing a font in my Info.plist (Fonts provided by application) that was not part of the application bundle.